# Neo4j - Duplicates Despite Using Merge

Tags: php, transactions, neo4j, cypher, neo4jphp

I am attempting to generate a database using `MERGE` statements through Neo4JPHP. All of my queries are using `MERGE`; however, it is generating separate nodes every time, resulting in massive duplication.

The queries are run within a single transaction. I've removed the surrounding code to focus on the queries:

```
$transaction = $client->beginTransaction();

while(...) {
    $pq = new Query($client, 'MERGE (n:Page {url:"'.$page.'"}) SET n.title="'.$title.'"');
    $transaction->addStatements(array($pageQuery));

    $h1Query = new Query($client, 'MATCH (n:Page {url:"'.$page.'"}) SET n.h1s = "['.implode(", ", $h1s).']"');
    $transaction->addStatements(array($h1Query));

    $scriptQuery = new Query($client, 'MATCH (n:Page {url:"'.$page.'"}) MERGE (n)-[:CONTAINS_SCRIPT]->(s:Script {url:"'.$s.'"})');
    $transaction->addStatements(array($scriptQuery));

    $styleQuery = new Query($client, 'MATCH (n:Page {url:"'.$page.'"}) MERGE (n)-[:CONTAINS_STYLESHEET]->(s:StyleSheet {url:"'.$s.'"})');
    $transaction->addStatements(array($styleQuery));

    $otherPageQuery = new Query($client, 'MATCH (n:Page {url:"'.$page.'"}) MERGE (n)-[:LINKS_TO]->(m:Page {url:"'.$match.'"})');
    $transaction->addStatements(array($otherPageQuery));
}

$transaction->commit();
```

Now, after running this across a couple of pages, it comes up with 6 copies of the same `Page`s, one with `title` and `h1s` elements, and the rest without.

I also tried using `CREATE UNIQUE`, but this gave an error that the syntax wasn't supported.

I am running Neo4j 2.0.1. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use `MERGE` on matches with relationships in Cypher, the entire object is being matched or created. When a match cannot be found, the entire object is created.

For example:

```
MERGE (n:Page { url: "http://www.neo4j.org" })
RETURN n
```

Gets or creates the `Page` with the property `url` set to `http://www.neo4j.org`. This statement will never create a duplicate node.

Now let's assume that this node now exists within the Neo4j database and then we run the following query:

```
MERGE (n:Page { url: "http://www.neo4j.org" })-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(test:Test { id: "test" })
RETURN *
```

This will attempt to match the entire pattern and if it does not exist, it will create the entire path regardless of whether or not the `Page` node exists.

To resolve your issue, make sure that you use `MERGE` to get or create your individual nodes first. Then you can use `MERGE` to get or create the relationship between the two nodes.

Example:

```
MERGE (n:Page { url: "http://www.neo4j.org" })
MERGE (s:StyleSheet { url: "http://www.neo4j.org/styles/main.css" })
MERGE (n)-[:CONTAINS_STYLESHEET]->(s)
RETURN *
```

Comment: Well, I guess it didn't work the way I expected. That seems to have fixed it. Thanks!